# Installing MinGW with Code::Blocks

Tags: installation, mingw, codeblocks

This is very strange for me. I have installed C::B with MinGW included. It works perfectly. But now I'm trying to change MinGW compiler manually - I downloaded MinGW from the official site and installed it. Then I just set up C::B as follows:

1. Change compiler's installation directory to the new MinGW folder
2. Change default debugger's executable path to the new one

After doing this I receive errors

```
undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_sj0'
undefined reference to `_Unwind_SjLj_Register'
undefined reference to `_Unwind_SjLj_Unregister'
```

It looks like I'm using inconsistent compilers or something, but everything is correct as I see it. Here are the screenshots of my settings

[compiler's settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yGADx.png)

[debugger's settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jmEUu.png)

All files (C, C++ compilers etc) are in the directory C:\MinGW\bin as they should be.

Comment: have you looked here? http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php/MinGW_installation,  looks like versions are incompatible or smthn

Comment: @hewi of course I looked.